# Sonarlint 2.3 eclipse issues shown on parent project

Tags: sonarlint-eclipse

I used Sonarlint 2.2.1 with Eclipse Luna, it was working quite well but since i've upgraded to Sonarlint 2.3, nothing works like before.

I use Sonarlint as a standalone eclipse plugin without a SonarQube server.

I work on a project with this kind of structure :

```
Parent
  |
  |-> module1
  |-> module2
  |-> ...
  |
```

In v2.2.1 sonarlint show all issues of all modules even if I close or delete the parent project from project.

In v2.3 sonarlint, no issue is displayed on the sonarlint view.

If I open `/module1/src/main/.../SomeClass.java`, then the issues of the current opened class are shown in the list but not inside the opened class.
And when I double-click on an issue in the list, it opens the file link to `/parent/module1/src/main/.../SomeClass.java` which is not considered as a file in the build path.
In the path column of the issues view, the path is like `/parent/module1/src/main/.../SomeClass.java`.

If I open a second class, the issues of that class come feeding the sonarlint issues view list.

**If I close the parent project** in eclipse, then I got an error telling me that the resources `/parent/module1/src/main/.../SomeClass.java` do not exist.

**If I delete the parent project** in eclipse, the issues are shown in the open file and the value of the column path in the sonarlint issues view is correct: `/module1/src/main/.../SomeClass.java`

Has anyone encountered the same problem?